# Aggregate average of model field with foreign key - Django REST

Tags: python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am creating a rating system using stars.

Here is my Place model:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    floor = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=5)
    address = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=120)
    desc = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is my rating model:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)

STAR_CONVERSION = (
    (1, 'One'),
    (2, 'Two'),
    (3, 'Three'),
    (4, 'Four'),
    (5, 'Five'),
    )

air_flow = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STAR_CONVERSION)``
```

I want to get the average rating for each rating field for each place.

For example, the average of air_flow for place X.

In my views.py I have tried to aggregate the average for air_flow for a unique place:

```
class PlaceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Place.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlaceSerializer

    air_flow_average = Rating.objects.filter(Place='id').aggregate(Avg('air_flow'))
```

Comment: figured it out, added a property decorator in the models instead of trying to calculate it in the views

`@property
         def average_rating(self):
          return Rating.objects.filter(place__id=self.id).aggregate(Avg('air_flow'))`

Comment: Does it appear in the database? And may you tell me how did you added it on the endpoint?